# PyQt installation 10.7 "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64"

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, homebrew

Trying to install PyQt on OS X 10.7:

```
g++ -headerpad_max_install_names -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -o w_qpyopengl.app/Contents/MacOS/w_qpyopengl    -F/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.6/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.6/lib -framework QtGui -L/opt/X11/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.6/lib -F/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.6/lib -framework QtCore 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.5.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [w_qpyopengl.app/Contents/MacOS/w_qpyopengl] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Make file was configured with

```
python configure.py -d /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ -g -q /usr/local/bin/qmake --use-arch=x86_64
```

$PATH is

```
/usr/local/bin/brew:/Users/username/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/smlnj-110.75/bin
```

$LIBRARY_PATH is

```
$ echo $LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/lib:
```

I've already tried sym linking /usr/lib to /opt/X11/lib (which didn't exist). crt1.10.5 can be found at

```
PyQt-mac-gpl-4.11 solidblanc$ locate crt1.10.5
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer
/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.10.5.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer
/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.10.5.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer
/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.10.5.o
/usr/lib/crt1.10.5.o
```

No idea what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `configure-ng.py` instead of `configure.py`. [This is apparently the recommended  approach these days.](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.pyqt-pykde/26996)

If you get the error `fatal error: sipAPIQtCore.h: No such file or directory`, try adding

```
INCPATH+=/path/to/PyQt-mac-gpl-4.11/_qt
```

to the `configure-mg.py` command. For example,

```
python configure-ng.py -g --sip-incdir=$HOME/Downloads/sip-4.16.1/siplib INCPATH+=$HOME/Downloads/PyQt-mac-gpl-4.11/_qt
```

If this builds a version of PyQt that crashes a lot (and it probably will, since it did for me), try configuring without `-g`.

Comment: With configure-ng I get tons of duplicate symbol errors: duplicate symbol __Z17qpycore_post_initP7_object in:
    qpycore_post_init.o
duplicate symbol _qpycore_signature_attr_name in:
    qpycore_post_init.o
duplicate symbol _qpycore_name_attr_name in:
    qpycore_post_init.o
ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64